# Should I unit test my /src files or /build files?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

When setting up unit tests (in my case, using Jasmine for JavaScript) should the un-minified/in-uglified `src` files be tested? Or should the end-user `build` files (minified and uglified) be tested?

In my grunt config:

```
jasmine: {
    src: ['src/file.js']
}
```

vs.

```
jasmine: {
    src: ['build/file.min.js']
}
```

On one hand, it's nice to test the `src` files since it doesn't remove debuggers and is easier to inspect when needed.

On the other hand, I can test the `src` files as much as I like but it's not true to what the end users will be running, as the `build` files are uglified and minified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should definitely unit test the bare source files as there were written. Unit tests are designed to be tightly focused and give you *instant and clear feedback*. In other words, if you test your functionality after the source code being modified - you are not testing your code in isolation; once you discover a bug, you cannot be 100% sure what caused it - it could be that there was a problem during the build that caused the problem - say the `uglify` task.

I would classify testing build files as a part of integration or a higher-level testing - since aside from testing functionality, you are also checking how your application was built: how the files were minified, copied, concatenated etc.

In general, you should aim to the following pyramid:

[image]

([introduced in this Google Test Automation blogpost](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html))

> On the other hand, I can test the src files as much as I like but it's
>   not true to what the end users will be running, as the build files are
>   uglified and minified.

I think this goes under the End-to-end testing category - imitating a real user, going through acceptance-testing scenarios, user stories.

Comment: Shouln't test be made to the final result, what if something went wrong when minifying the files ?

Comment: @DanielPérez sure, but this kind of problems should be caught by the high-level smoke or end-to-end tests.